How to resolve SSL Error with IBM RAD 9 talking to Websphere v85 - SSLC0008E - for local development with security enabled
We are getting this error that prevents development with RAD IDE v9 and Websphere Traditional Application v8.
The full specific versions are listed below.
We have not deployed any code but just have RAD and our security configuration and trying to start and stop the server.  The server may or not stop or start after the timeout period.
We suspect it is some communcation issue between RAD and Websphere.
We have the server configured listed below.  And then we enable custom LDAP application security and security in general.
After starting or stoppping the server, we get this error. Really two errors about the same time.
10/10/24 13:57:29:130 EDT] 00000001 BatchSensorCo I   CWLRB5904I: BatchSensorComponent starting...
[10/10/24 13:57:29:162 EDT] 00000054 SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection.  Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired.  Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
      at com.ibm.jsse2.c.a(c.java:12)
      at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:257)
      at com.ibm.jsse2.as.unwrap(as.java:528)
      at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:5)
      at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:586)
      at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:346)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
      at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
      at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
      at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
      at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
      at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
.
[10/10/24 13:57:29:193 EDT] 00000001 BatchSensorCo I   CWLRB5905I: Successfully activated GridEndpointSensorMBean.
[10/10/24 13:57:29:193 EDT] 00000001 RMIConnectorC A   ADMC0026I: The RMI Connector is available at port 2810
[10/10/24 13:57:29:193 EDT] 00000001 JMXConnectors I   ADMC0058I: The JMX JSR160RMI connector is available at port 2810
[10/10/24 13:57:29:224 EDT] 00000001 WsServerImpl  A   WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business
[10/10/24 13:57:29:981 EDT] 00000042 RoleBasedAuth A   SECJ0305I: The role-based authorization check failed for admin-authz operation AdminService:pullNotifications:com.ibm.ws.management.event.ListenerIdentifier:java.lang.Integer.  The user UNAUTHENTICATED (unique ID: unauthenticated) was not granted any of the following required roles: configurator, administrator, auditor, monitor, deployer, adminsecuritymanager, operator.

We have tried a couple of different thing including.
Beginning with java version 8.0.7.5 it became necessary to modify RAD's ssl.client.props file to specify "SSL_TLSv2" instead of "SSL_TLS" for the com.ibm.ssl.protocol property eg:Navigate to the <INSTALL_DIRECTORY>/runtimes/base_stub/properties folder.  This first appeared  as an issue in RAD version 9.7.0.5.
Example path: C:\IBM\SDP97\runtimes\base_stub\properties
This does not fix the problem.
Also tried changing the QOP settings or inbound csi v2 connections to tcp/ip ssl not required
From my understanding, we talked to the websphere and rad people, doesn't seem to be a websphere issue but rad communication issue.
here are some settings:
WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.15 [BASE 8.5.5.15 cf151904.01] running with process name SomeUser-101Node02Cell\SomeUser-101Node02\server1 and process id 12236
Host Operating System is Windows 10, version 10.0
Java version = 1.8.0_191, Java Runtime Version = 8.0.5.27 - pwa6480sr5fp27-20190104_01(SR5 FP27), Java Compiler = j9jit29, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85
user.install.root = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv02PolNewCarSucksNoMore
Java Home = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/java/lib;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv02PolNewCarSucksNoMore/classes;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/classes;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/installedChannels;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/ext;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/web/help;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\profiles\AppSrv02PolNewCarSucksNoMore/properties;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/properties;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/startup.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85/lib/native/win/x86_64/;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\java\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\lib\native\win\x86_64;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\bin;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\java\bin;C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\java\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Temurin\bin;C:\WINDOWS\CCM;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Hummingbird\Connectivity\15.00\Accessories;C:\Program Files\WinMerge;C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.;
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb80-20181016.00
Max file descriptor count = --
Rad:
Version: 9.7.0.5
Build ID: RADO9.7.0.5-I20220615_1528
(c) Copyright IBM Corp. 2000, 2016 and other(s). (c) Copyright HCL Technologies Limited. 2016, 2022.  All rights reserved.

Ok, correct the tag
